# fullwidth: Trying to change paragraph margins doesn't work as expected

Tags: indentation, fullwidth

The [fullwidth](http://ctan.org/pkg/fullwidth) package (current version 0.1) by [Marco Daniel](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/5239/marco-daniel) *"provides the environment `fullwidth` which allows to set the left and right margins in a very simple way"* (manual, p. 1). According to the manual, the package is based on the algorithm of the [mdframed](http://ctan.org/pkg/mdframed) package (current version 1.0) by the same author.

However, trying to change margins of individual paragraphs with `fulllwidth` doesn't yield the desired results. Setting the `leftmargin` option to a positive value will move the whole paragraph to the right (into the right page margin), and setting `rightmargin` to a positive value doesn't have any effect at all. (The `mdframed` package, on the other hand, changes the respective margins as expected [and adds a frame around the paragraph].) `fullwidth`s behaviour can't be correct, can it?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[linewidth=1.2pt]{mdframed}
\usepackage{fullwidth}

\newcommand*{\sometext}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer
    adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac,
    adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauris. Nam arcu
    libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna. Donec
    vehicula augue eu neque.}

\begin{document}

\section{\texttt{mdframed} works as expected}

\sometext

\begin{mdframed}[leftmargin=3em]
\sometext
\end{mdframed}

\begin{mdframed}[rightmargin=3em]
\sometext
\end{mdframed}

\section{But \texttt{fullwidth} doesn't}

\sometext

\begin{fullwidth}[leftmargin=3em]
\sometext
\end{fullwidth}

\begin{fullwidth}[rightmargin=3em]
\sometext
\end{fullwidth}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @MarcoDaniel: You might be interested in this one.

Comment: I am interested ;-). The output of `fullwidth` is inside `\leftmargin` instead `mdframed` uses a combination of `\makebox`. I have no problem to discuss the behavior. At the moment you must set the `width` (good or not?). That `rightmargin` has no influence is really a bug.

Comment: @Marco: I think `mdframed`s behaviour for `leftmargin=3em` (adding a left margin of 3em and *not* changing the right margin) is more intuitive. It also corresponds to the working of `KOMA-Script`s `addmargin` environment.

Comment: In relation to `addmargin` it is easier for the user. I will change that. Please note it is version 0.1 so I will change some settings ;-) https://github.com/marcodaniel/fullwidth

Comment: @MarcoDaniel: I really like the idea of key--value syntax. I'm also aware that the package version is 0.1 (and did mention the fact in my question). I was simply expecting a behaviour similar to that of `mdframed`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

@lockstep: Do you think that the following behavior is more efficient?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage[linewidth=1.2pt]{mdframed}
\usepackage{fullwidth}

\newcommand*{\sometext}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer
    adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac,
    adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauris. Nam arcu
    libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna. Donec
    vehicula augue eu neque.}

\makeatletter
\def\fullwidth@i[#1]{% default-Umgebung
  \begingroup
  \fullwidthsetup{#1}%%
   \fwd@twoside@checklength%
   \ifbool{fwd@twosidemode}%
    {\advance\fwd@width@length by -\fwd@outermargin@length
     \advance\fwd@width@length by -\fwd@outermargin@length}%
    {\advance\fwd@width@length by -\fwd@leftmargin@length
     \advance\fwd@width@length by -\fwd@rightmargin@length}%
   \let\width\z@%
   \let\height\z@%
   \setlength{\topsep}{\fwd@skipabove@length}%
   \begingroup%
     \let\partopsep\z@%
   \expandafter\endgroup%   
   \begin{fwd@trivlist}\item\relax%
   \hsize=\fwd@width@length\relax%
   \fwd@footnoteinput%
   \begin{fwd@lrbox}{\@tempboxa}%
 }
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{\texttt{mdframed} works as expected}

\sometext

\begin{mdframed}[leftmargin=3em]
\sometext
\end{mdframed}

\begin{mdframed}[rightmargin=3em]
\sometext
\end{mdframed}

\section{But \texttt{fullwidth} doesn't}

\sometext

\begin{fullwidth}[leftmargin=3em]
\sometext
\end{fullwidth}

\begin{fullwidth}[rightmargin=3em]
\sometext
\end{fullwidth}

\null\hfill\smash{\rule[1.5cm]{3em}{2pt}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It resembles `mdframed` and therefore is what I expected (at least with respect to left and right margins). Perhaps the vertical skip before and after the `fullwidth` environment should also be 0pt by default. But you're the package author. ;-)

Comment: @lockstep: I am happy about every comment ;-)

Comment: I will read the manual thoroughly in the next weeks to see if I can come up with further suggestions for "self-explanatory" behaviour. (And I'm glad that I pointed you to a real bug.)